# Intranet HTML files on Jquery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a system for users to access a certain application on the work intranet. Basically, i have them pointed to a splash index.html page which has links that point to other network drive some of which users have rights to and some which they do not. My thinking was that i could use this to mimic Active Directory and allow certain aspects of the "site" to be viewable by certain individuals.

It works well if i am just navigating the browser from html page to html page. However, i would like to load html files through the jquery load function to populate the main html page that all users have access to using div elements (my thinking is that i will get an access denied AJAX error when a user tries to access a page that points to a network drive that they do not have security rights to). My initial research into this came with the following code (which i stole):

```
 $("#BUT").click(function() {
            $("#t").load( "PROD.html #Navigation", function( response, status, xhr ) {
              if ( status == "error" ) {
                  var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                      $( "#t" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
                        }
                        });
     });
```

The problem is that no matter what i put into the first parameter, i get an access denied error. The file there is in the same directory as the script file.

I have tried this on all browsers using all sorts of files and i have yet to get it to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: The error information is as follows: the statusText is "Error: Access is denied.", the status is 0, the readyState is 0, the response is undefined and the status is error.

Comment: Can you include the access denied error exacty as it appears in your console?

Comment: Could you try copying that Javascript from a JS file into your HTML file?

Comment: @Shriike. I could try. But it is accessing the function, the error is being printed to the #t tag.

Comment: you're not working from file:/// are you?

Comment: @KevinB im loading the PROD file exactly as seen in OP

Comment: Right, but is your browser pointing to file:///somepage.html?

Comment: There's only a select few things that can cause "Access Denied", and by using PROD.html the way you are, it rules out most of them.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're trying to work off of file://D/foo/bar/page.html which is going to have problems with ajax.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. I am running the file off of the drive. Its strictly for the intranet, so i point IE to \\SERVER\folder\file.html and thats the file that calls the functions above. Do you think this is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

`PROD.html #Navigation` looks like you're trying to jump to a particular section in PROD.html.

If that's the case try `$("#t").load( "PROD.html", ...` instead:

```
$("#t").load( "PROD.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    if ( status == "error" ) {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $( "#t" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
    }
    else {
        $('#Navigation')[0].scrollIntoView(); // <-- Move to #Navigation
    }
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Thats a legal thing to do either way though, right? The jquery documentation implies that i can add a tag to jump to in the new html file.

Comment: @brhardwick My bad, I wasn't aware of that feature, however, looking at the docs, that `#Navigation` would actually only load that section, so it's not a way of jumping either.